# Opera failed to start: "The specified procedure could not be found"

Tags: windows-vista, opera

I decided to give Opera another spin. I downloaded the new Opera 12.12 version, overlooking the fact that I had an older Opera still on my PC. This didn't turn out to be a problem. Opera neatly updated to 12.12. After a couple of hours, I exited Opera and tried to start it up again.

I got the following message on Opera's startup:

> Opera failed to start because: The specified procedure could not be found.

I tried to uninstall Opera but ended up in the same error message.

Next step: I followed [these instructions](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1603012)

1. delete all files under `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Opera`
2. delete all files under `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Opera`
3. delete all files under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Opera`
4. Run CCleaner to clean your registry
5. Download the [latest Opera installer](http://www.opera.com/download/) and install it

So I reinstalled Opera which worked. But when I tried to start Opera I get same error again.

I would love to get Opera going again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to try and remove it complete from your system, it sounds like it is referencing the wrong version (or that it doesn't realist it's all been removed.

> Before you proceed with removing Opera, it is important that you know
>   where Opera stores its settings. In Opera, go to Help > About Opera.
>   Under "Paths" in the About Opera page, look for the path to your
>   preferences - the Opera6.ini file. Take note of this path, as it will
>   be needed to completely remove Opera from your system.
>
> 1. Uninstalling Opera
>
> To uninstall Opera, open the Control Panel from the Start menu in
>   Windows. In the Control Panel, open "Add or Remove Programs", and
>   locate Opera in the list of installed programs. Click "Remove" to
>   uninstall Opera.
>
> Please note that this will not remove user created files and settings.
>
> 2. Removing user created files
>
> In order to completely remove an Opera installation, the following
>   directories must be removed after performing a normal uninstall:
>
> ```
> The folder you installed Opera to.
> The Opera settings folder.
> ```
>
> If you chose not to use separate settings for each user when
>   installing Opera, you will only have to remove your Opera installation
>   folder. To find out if this is the case, look at the location of the
>   file Opera6.ini, which you found earlier, and compare it to the path
>   to your main Opera installation folder.
>
> If the location of the Opera6.ini file is different from the location
>   of opera.exe, you are using separate settings for each user, and will
>   have to delete two folders manually.
>
> Before proceeding, you may wish to take a backup of your files in case
>   you wish to install Opera again:
>
> http://www.opera.com/support/search/view/313/
>
> To remove the remaining files on your system, simply delete the Opera
>   installation folder. If the Opera6.ini is separate for each user (in a
>   different location than opera.exe, make sure you delete the folder
>   where this file can be found as well.

[Source](http://www.opera.com/support/kb/view/623/)

I have also seen people recommend this [tool called Revo](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html).
[Source for tool recommendation](http://my.opera.com/DuncanWilliams/blog/make-your-windows-computer-more-secure)

Comment: Well, the first part of this, finding out the path, I can't, as Opera want start up anymore. Uninstall, well, as you can read in my OP, I can't, same error. I did delete every opera file I could find (maybe I mist some? See the directories in my OP). So I'm sorry to say, but this quote from opera support wasn't very helpful.

Comment: The second part of your advice, the Revo tool, did the trick! I installed it and let it handle the uninstall with a "deep scan" for left over files and registry entries. After that I could install Opera again and it's working! Cheers!

Comment: @Peter I recommend you to choose the portable installation. This way Opera won't write anything to your registry and you avoid those problems in the future.